# Multiple Views on one template in Django

Tags: python, django

Essentially I want to have a login on my home page. The login view is found in "django.contrib.auth.views.login" which I don't believe I have access to. But then it also needs to have a view which deals with all the other bits going on on the home page. I would combine these into one view but since I don't appear to have access to the login views I dont think I can do this.

If there is another way of doing this rather than having two views on one template that would be great I'm quite new to web deving so I'm not sure of what the "right" way to do things is.

Many thanks

Comment: You don't need two views on that same page. Just you just need to pass the login form to the home page view.

Comment: Sorry could you explain how i would go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

```
def index_view(request):
    return render(request, 'homepage.html')
```

In your homepage.html just pass django login url

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
```

**Updates**

Please include url also

```
(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
```

Please follow this [login](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.login) for more details...

Comment: I put in this code precisely and got the error that: ViewDoesNotExist at /

Comment: Sorry i thought you having the django login url as well

Comment: If you `name` the login URL, you can just refer to it as something like `{% url 'login' %}`

Comment: That didnt help, Ive follow the tutorial ie i copied and pasted it and i still got the same error

Comment: @RoboPython Please be elaborate as your question seems very abstract and we could only guess your problem and answer